# Раннее и позднее связывание. Статическая и динамическая типизация

Tags: java, c++, ооп

Java и C++ - языки со статической типизацией, т.е. тип известен в момент объявления поля (`String str;`). 
 В одном видеоуроке, раннее и позднее связывание ассоциировали с статической и динамической типизацией соответственно. Но думаю, автор хотел сказать, статическое и динамическое связывание, т.к. к типизации это отношения не имеет .  Я ведь прав?

Так же часто пишут, что в Java есть только позднее связывание. Ну а как же статические методы? Вот пример с JavaRush. Создаем экземпляр производного класса и неявно приводим его к базовому. В этом экземпляре будут все методы базового класса (в переопределенном виде, если они переопределены в производном классе). Но как и полагалось статические методы не переопределяются и вызовется метод из базового класса. А раз это заранее известно, то компилятор использует раннее связывание, это можно увидеть с помощью определенной команды в консоли. Можно увидеть как помечены методы. 
Хотел бы узнать, правильно ли сказать, что в Java есть и раннее связывание? 
Напомните пожалуйста эту консольную команду, чтобы увидеть как методы помечены.

```
    public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Пример статического и динамического связывания в Java
    Insurance current = new CarInsurance();

    // Динамическое связывание на основе объекта
    int premium = current.premium();

    // Статическое связывание на основе класса
    String category = current.category();

    System.out.println("premium : " + premium);
    System.out.println("category : " + category);
  }
}

class Insurance{
  public static final int LOW = 100;

  public int premium(){
    return LOW;
  }

  public static String category(){
    return "Insurance";
  }

}

class CarInsurance extends Insurance{
  public static final int HIGH = 200;

  public int premium(){
    return HIGH;
  }

  public static String category(){
    return "Car Insurance";
  }

}
```

Результаты выполнения:

```
premium : 200
category : Insurance
```

И кстати, полиморфизм подтипов это ведь и есть позднее связывание? Вернее полиморфизм подтипов обеспечивается за счет позднего связывания. Так?

Comment: Статика в джаве не подразумевает полиморфизма, поэтому про позднее связывание в контексте статики говорить немного некорректно (нет никаких причин его реализовывать).

Comment: да, переопределять смысла нет, но статический метод компилятор всё равно помечает каким то образом, найти бы эту команду, чтобы эти пометки видеть. И такой метод уже связывается на раннем этапе.

Comment: Он не помечает метод, он пишет инструкцию invokestatic в байт-код. При этом invokestatic ссылается ровно на такой же MethodRef, как и обычный invokevirtual. Как именно происходит выбор метода в рантайме, рассказать не смогу.

Comment: Консольная программа, дизасемблирующая байткод Java классов - `javap`, идёт в комплекте с JDK. Использование - `javap -v com.example.MyClass`. В байткоде можно увидеть, что все нестатические методы вызываются через `invokevirtual`, даже если класс точно известен на момент компиляции, а статические - через `invokestatic`. Выбор метода в рантайме описан [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokevirtual).